# Draw graph with sql variables

Tags: php, sql, google-visualization

I used Google graph to draw a graph by below code, but the problem is that my data is on a sql table, how can I put my table variables into this graph?

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses'],
      ['2004',  1000,      400],
      ['2005',  1170,      460],
      ['2006',  660,       1120],
      ['2007',  1030,      540]
    ]);

    var options = {
      title: 'Company Performance'
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You must `SELECT` the data on the php file where you prepare this page you posted and then `echo` the data as the format you show in your sample code.

Comment: I want your sql table structure

Comment: You first need to extract the data from the database - the recommend approach for PHP in this day and age is to just [PHP Data Objects](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: @SnowBlind number of rows are not specified, every time it changed, how to echo them?

Comment: @r.vengadesh I have table named result with two column: attempt and login, every time that visitor loged in one row adds

Comment: @SunnyLeone You have to echo them row by row of course, with a loop or something.

Comment: @SnowBlind the point is here? how to make that loop, how to put my variables in var data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php


$result = mysql_query("SELECT year,sales,expenses from tablename");
$value=array();
while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
$year=$r['year'];
$sales=$r['sales'];
$expenses=$r['expenses'];
$val="[".$year.",".$sales.",".$expenses."]";
array_push($value,$val );
}
$final_value = implode(",", $value);

?>
```

**put this $final_value into google chart**

```
function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      <?php echo $final_value?>
    ]);

    var options = {
      title: 'Company Performance'
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
```

Comment: what is $array in `$final_value = implode(",", $array);` ?

Comment: sorry change $array into $ value @SunnyLeone

Answer (score 0):

Retrieve your data From tables by querying database and convert it to JSON string. Then pass your json string to your variable

```
var data=/*your json string*/
```

Comment: I am new to PHP and SQL, could you help me more, how to do this?

Comment: You can get some ideas by visiting posts like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10045341/converting-a-mysql-query-to-a-json-object-using-php

Answer (score 0):

```
$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'pass', 'demo');

if($db->connect_errno > 0){
    die('Unable to connect to database [' . $db->connect_error . ']');
}

$sql = "SELECT attempt, login FROM result";

if(!$result = $db->query($sql)){
    die('There was an error running the query [' . $db->error . ']');
}

echo "var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([['Attempt', 'Login']";

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    echo ",['".$row['attempt'] ."','".$row['attempt']."']";
}

echo "]);";

$result->free();

$db->close();
```

Comment: there is error on `echo "var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([['Attempt', 'Login']";`

Comment: @SunnyLeone Editted the answer, please try again.